# Late 2011 15" MBP - keyboard and trackpad cease to work after 1 month following clean install

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011) 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7 with the faulty AMD Radeon HD 6770M dedicated GPU running OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

The issue is that the keyboard and trackpad cease to work after 1 month or so after a clean install.

I have tried most of the tricks [found here](https://setapp.com/how-to/quickly-fix-your-macbook-keyboard-not-working-issue) and have even changed the keyboard a couple of years ago. However I am now almost sure that the problem is on the software side because every time I perform a clean OS X install, the keyboard and trackpad work perfectly well for around 1 month. Then just suddenly stop working. Also, whenever I enter the boot menu on startup (holding `alt` key), the keyboard and trackpad are perfectly responsive.

I now know that I could just keep performing clean installs every month to keep them working but is however very tedious. Also the `.plist` files deletion trick usually gives best results bringing the keyboard back for 2 or 3 days but after performing the trick 3 times or so, it does not work anymore...

What else can I check to keep them operational?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in a comment below, I booted into safe mode by holding Shift while powering on. Tried this several times and the problem persisted while on safe mode, no integrated keyboard, no integrated trackpad...

Comment: Fist thing, let’s see if it’s something getting loaded that’s not part of macOS itself.  Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) by holding Shift while powering on.  Does the problem still exist?  Update your question with the results

Comment: Ok...so, it’s something with macOS itself.  Before you reinstall the OS, install to a USB flash or external drive (flash is cheaper and easier), then boot from that.  It won’t be fast, but it’s just to test for now. Don’t forget to do a Time Machine backup

Comment: @Allan Sorry for the long delay. I have installed the OS into an external hard drive. It is not fast but OK, however, and surprisingly, I still have no integrated keyboard nor trackpad when booting into the external drive. However, I still get them *sometimes* at the boot menu...

Comment: That tells me you’ve got a hardware issue.  The top case may be faulty or the logic board may have a problem with the USB bus where the top case connects to.  Unfortunately, you’ve got to send it in for service

Comment: @Allan I just recovered the trackpad and keyboard unexpectedly. What happened is that I installed Paragon NTFS for Mac 15. I am supposing it modified something in the system that somehow brought back the hardware. I immediately turned off the bluetooth but I guess that this will last for just a few days. Any idea as to what could have been modified that brought back the hardware?

Comment: Hardware doesn’t resurrect.  There’s nothing in Paragon NTFS that affects your keyboard.  This is why I had you boot with a clean OS, if it failed there, it’s hardware.  3rd party software can’t “modify” hardware to make it functional with a virgin OS.  What I think could be the issue is your battery may be swelling and causing connections to break,  if the swelling dissipated, the connections came back together snd the top case then started to work.